# Infer types in generic class

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to infer types from a generic class?

In the example below I'd like to infer the types in the Component class to get the type and the value:

```
class Obj<T,V>{
    constructor(type: T, value: V){
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
    type: T
    value: V
}
class TextObj extends Obj<"text" | "email", string>{
    
}

class Component<O extends Obj<infer F, infer V>> {
    constructor(obj: O){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    obj: O
    
    getValue():V {
        return this.obj.value;
    }
    
    getType():F {
        return this.obj.type;
    }
}

class TextComponent extends Component<TextObj>{

}

let txtComp = new TextComponent(new TextObj("text", "some Text"));

let value = txtComp.getValue();
     //^--- should be string
```

[available as TS Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArAPAFQDTQGoD5oG8BYAKGjOmAHsA7CAFwCcBXYOyhgCjoE8AHAUwBc0DNABuYEEyHYAlARLkl0OgAsAlhAB0PAdAC8KvvwDci5WTWatEqfwPjJ0s6XIBfc5ePDUnx3eEsEg9iElBIGFR+AA86BERoGLp+agATGHjkACJk2KzoAB9oLP4AWzB1ECzMegZ1agBzPCJQ4hCw8ChoAGFKUt4aFLpkWETYlPS4JGR6gDN+BmgAMUw5hewcZr8qWkYWNk5KJGFYeRaLSw1tI4TDG5cldtcyG5OSPwb+Oiwnfg5ZQIKZ7KBhfJgMagqK5aG42X4PdzvYGfOioYz-YRLIEXaCgujgyFWa5IHTGBFkEJPcJdKKxXr9QbUOhjZJpGD0gbUIZoJLxLatJ4gL4qOl9XgOLkAdxESQ5jLoHClMti8Q4OSS1WKED69lpdCyslkLhIQuZtmkDjoov6WhRPzs-3JZAA9M6AHoAWi90AgqkoTBAqWg8HstXqDSAA)

Comment: Can you just unwrap this type variable in other direction? I mean replacing V and F with `O['value']` and O[`type`]` and extending `Obj<unknown, unknown>`

Comment: @STerliakov that's how I'd do it.  As shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJrvgW).  NicoRichter does that work for you?  If so maybe STerliakov can write up an answer.  If not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz yep, it's what I suggested, just unable to write a good answer from phone. Will do in a few hours

Comment: @STerliakov Yes thank you, that works for me. And I will use it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to infer type variables like this, you can access them indirectly. Since both are conveniently exposed as property types, you can use item access syntax:

```ts
class Component<O extends Obj<unknown, unknown>> {
    constructor(obj: O) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    obj: O

    getValue(): O['value'] {
        return this.obj.value;
    }

    getType(): O['type'] {
        return this.obj.type;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArAPAFQDTQGoD5oG8BYAKGjOmAHsA7CAFwCcBXYOyhgCjoE8AHAUwBc0DNABuYEEyHYAlARLkl0OgAsAlhAB0PAdAC8KvvwDci5WTWatEqfwPjJ0s6XIBfc5ePDUnx3eEsEg9iElBIGFR+AA86BERoGLp+agATGHjkACJk2KzoAB9oLP4AWzB1ECzMegZ1agBzPCJXMgAzSkphWvqGhyz84JIw8ChoAGFKUt4aFLpkWETYlPS4JGQmagBrakoAd2pMTZ396hxmvypaRhY2TkokYVh5FotLDW0HhMMvlyUQvxfJ7DVrQBr8OhYJz8DiyJ4AbQA5LZpIiALoKUFKBgQpgMagqD5aL42aF-dwgpTguioYywhGI3T8dGYt7QHF0PEEqyfJA6YzksghAHEcJjKKxSbTWbUOhLZJpGBSmbUOZoJLxC7EEUgCEqSVTXgOVV7ERJZUyugcE1m2LxDg5JLVYoQKb2CV0LKyWQuEh0A3TYl8jqUMgAejD0AA6vZ6JUQNATqa1PZNql+AwQNxekY9LwccBNPws5hdnKwGCUhn1MBoLwwDjZSRdXKUfZDP66MqtNSoXZYeSIwA9AD8QA)

Answer (score 0):

try this following and let me konw it that you wanted

```
class Obj<T, V> {
    constructor(type: T, value: V) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
    type: T
    value: V
}

class TextObj extends Obj<"text" | "email", string> {

}

class Component<O extends Obj<infer F, infer V>> {
    constructor(obj: O) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    obj: O

    getValue(): V {
        return this.obj.value;
    }

    getFormat(): F {
        return this.obj.type;
    }
}

class TextComponent extends Component<TextObj> {

}

let txtComp = new TextComponent(new TextObj("text", "some Text"));

txtComp.getValue();
```

Comment: You found a typo, so sorry for my failure. I will change this in my question. My problem is this codeline `class Component<O extends Obj<infer F, infer V>>`. Typescript tells me `'infer' declarations are only permitted in the 'extends' clause of a conditional type.` But I don't know how to do this.